# Different animations for jQuery UI dialog close depending on button?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible (in a reasonalbe way) to have a jQuery UI dialog closed with different animations depending on which button that is clicked?

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "explode"
    buttons: {
        "Delete": function () {
             ... one animation here ...
             $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Cancel" : function () {
            ... another here ...
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep.

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
    //autoOpen: false,
    show: 'blind',
    buttons: {
        Delete: function () {
            $( this ).dialog( 'option', 'hide', 'explode' );
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel : function () {
            $( this ).dialog( 'option', 'hide', 'blind' );
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/GLUHa/2/